# iPhone app crashing on some devices -- looking for advice

Tags: iphone, crash

Hey everyone, I'm in a bit of a pickle and am looking for some advice.
I have an app that's been released to the app store..nothing special just a first time sort of thing. The app runs perfectly fine on my device(s) but a couple buddies always get a crash.
So here's the details:

It crashes by sometimes stalling and other times by just exiting to the main screen.

- I've tried to replicate the crash (or any crash) using

  - the same iPhone generation/model
  - on an ipod touch as well
  - the same OS
  - different OS
  - using debug/release/distribution/downloading from app store builds
  - since it's an app that connects to a google maps service, I've tried with both
    a wifi connection and the att network.

The only thing that MAY be different is any other apps on their phones that are not on mine.

The fact that I cannot replicate with exactly the same setup leads me to believe it's a memory issue, maybe uninitialized variables or incorrect cleanup at some point (i'm from C++, so I know this sort of thing can vary from machine to machine). I'm somewhat new to obj C and may very well be missing something there. I'm just curious to hear what others have to say, does this sound like a memory issue with the info I've provided? Any other ideas to test/suggestions come to mind to try and reproduce the crash?

Thanks!

Comment: Does your app use a lot of memory when put in the foreground? If so, failure by the OS to allocate new memory chunks might be a reason.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that it's a backgrounding issue. You don't say whether your app tries to use those features or whether your friends experience the crash in that context, so it's hard to say.

I would provision your friends with a beta that logs verbosely if you can't pin it down.

Comment: I'll look into giving them a version that logs, that's a good idea. What did you mean by "backgrounding" exactly?